# Error while deserializing SAML2 response to Saml2SecurityToken

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a SAML Reponse which I want to convert to a Saml2SecurityToken.
This is what I do:

```
// SAMLResponseString is a base64 encode SAML2 XML string
string SAMLResponse = SamlHelper.DecodeFrom64(SAMLResponseString);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(SAMLResponse));

var certificate = new X509Certificate2("[path]", "[password]");
List<SecurityToken> tokens = new List<SecurityToken>();
tokens.Add(new X509SecurityToken(certificate));

SecurityTokenResolver outOfBandTokenResolver =
  SecurityTokenResolver.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenResolver(new 
  ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityToken>(tokens), true);
var securityToken = (Saml2SecurityToken) WSSecurityTokenSerializer.DefaultInstance.ReadToken(reader, null);
```

On the last line (of the WSSecurityTokenSerializer), I get the following error:

```
Cannot read the token from the 'Response' element with the 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol' namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a '' ValueType. If this element is expected to be valid, ensure that security is configured to consume tokens with the name, namespace and value type specified.
```

My Response is starting with: (without the space between < and samlp:Response):

```
< samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0">
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

While .NET supports SAML2 assertions (from .NET 4.5), it doesn't support the SAML2 protocol, that `samlp:Response` belongs to. You need to either roll your own code to get the assertion out of the response message and pass that to the framework methods, or use a third party library.

I've written an [open source library](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) for processing incoming SAML2 responses in ASP.NET applications, there you can find code for reading and validating the response message and converting it to a .NET identity.